# Level Shifting - Signal Scaling - Scale Analog Signal Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, level-shifting, logic-level, level-translation

I have a variable voltage called `Vreg` (Voltage regulated) which is output of switching regulator (buck converter) and is less than 12v.

Also there is ANALOG Signal with voltage between `0 < V < Vreg < 12v`. (Vreg is less than `12v`). I need to scale my ANALOG signal from `0 < V < Vreg` span to `0 < V < 5v` span so that I can read it directly with Arduino. Also need it be economic with few parts or easily available parts like very common op-amps etc. Signal frequency is less than `50 KHz`.

**Further Clarification:**

The problem is that I have a DC FAN with an integrated RPM sensor. It have three exposed pins.

- GND
- VCC
- RPM Signal (Tach OUT)

Module Contains a DC motor, and sensor output is analog. Internal schematic of module is like this:

[image]

[image taken from here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94656/tacheo)

I need to control the rpm of motor, but the module do not have such capability so i need to play with input voltage `VCC` to module.  I've checked and it did work to control RPM. It can go down to near `0v`, but the problem is with Tach pin's signal which have no sufficient voltage if module input voltage is near `0v`. How i can overcome this?

I need an Intermediate circuit for this, and cannot use extra pin of UC like some answers below.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason a resistive divider wouldn't work?

Comment: I think yes, `Vreg` is adjustable (variable) and can go less than `5v`. Thus signal logic level will be less than `5v` and i think divider will not work. Also signal is analog

Comment: You seem to be mixing analog and digital. If so then you need to specify a switching threshold. The question is unclear. Can you draw a graph of output desired vs input voltage. Tip: 'V' for volt. 'k' for kilo. You've written '50 kelvin-hertz'.

Comment: How will you deal with the case when Vreg is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you want to know the ratio of your analog sensor's output in relation to your supply voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi5Z6K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Use a pair of 12:5 potential dividers to divide both the supply voltage and the analog sensor voltage by the same amount. Calculate the ratio in software.*